# A non-numeric value encountered getCalculatedValue

Tags: laravel, phpspreadsheet

I'm having trouble saving the file xlsx when the data has function

[E22] = PMT (D20 / 12, D19, -E23, D7.0)

environment:

laravel 5.8

php 7.1

phpoffice/phpspreadsheet [1.7.0] - 2019-05-26

```
public function gen_file_download_tt(&$result) {

        $language = $this->getlocal();
        $excel_tempate = public_path(). "/excel/template/truyenthong_".$language.".xlsx";
        $ex = new Excel();
        $ex->load($excel_tempate);


        $file_name = 'BangTinh_TruyenThong_Thang_'.Date('YmdHis').'.xlsx';
        $excel_result = public_path(). "/excel/download/".$file_name;
        $ex->save($excel_result);

        $ex->free();
        return $file_name;
    }
```

excel resource($excel_tempate):  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iJY5_F0TNrVWQfkUxaAVj-XMquYfnMOO/view?usp=sharing

opening up and saving will get the following error:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FfwjooMKOABZmuDfuCvfoBKUsrTcgFWd/view?usp=sharing

This error is not affected by other normal excel files

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of the error here

`[E22] = PMT (D20 / 12, D19, -E23, D7.0)`

error returned value: #VALUE

so open excel does not save.